# Advocate for the pop-culture idea of withholding vaccination

Tags: biochemistry, immunology, bacteriology, virology, immune-system

While it is widely accepted that vaccination is preferable to not vaccinating, would anyone like to give a shot at providing evidence in favor of not vaccinating? Anything goes.

Comment: This is a scientifically minded site. Why would you think we would want to engage in such a waste of time?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the thing. **No one** has been able to repeat the results seen in the discredited "vaccination is linked to autism" study that started this whole dangerous mess (I'm not even going to bother looking up the citation, I care that little about it). Scientists, including those funded by so-called "anti-vax" groups, have been trying for the past 15-20ish years, and they **can't do it**, because

***there is no causative link between early-childhood vaccination and autism***.

Your question is akin to asking us to advocate against Pasteur's germ theory of disease, or for the idea of [phlogiston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phlogiston_theory) in chemistry, or against the theory of relativity in physics.

So, given that the scientific evidence is firmly pointing in one direction, why would we waste our time on this endeavor, especially when anti-vaxxers will cling to any sort of misquoted, out-of-context, partial evidence that they can find?

The only reason a child should not receive a vaccine at the scheduled time and in the recommended dose would be because she is severely allergic to one of the main components of the vaccine, or she has a significantly-depressed immune system, typically associated with cancer and other severe medical conditions. At such times, medical recommendations by the specialist treating the condition should be followed.

Comment: Really good answer, however I don't want to vote up, because then the question will hang around even if closed. Maybe it should become a community wiki on why early childhood vaccination? Or an ask and answer? I'd vote up.

Comment: @AMR I wrote it out of frustration and because I didn't want to take 4 comments to say the same thing, not for upvotes :) The question can still be (manually) deleted after closure if enough 10K+ users vote to, so get your lobbying skills to work!

Comment: This has been covered already [on Skeptics](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/607/are-there-any-other-studies-besides-the-discredited-wakefield-studies-that-hav) and [Health](http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/357/do-vaccines-cause-autism), so I don't see the need to cover it again here.

Comment: Not to mention that "study" wasn't even a study at all. It was "hey, I looked at the guts of 6 of my patients and now I am convinced vaccines cause autism". What the heck? It's been retracted and denounced by the journal that published it by now, anyway.

Comment: Phlogiston! :'D

Comment: @DonJulian and why is that? Because we rigorously tested a hypothesis, found it to have no support, and discarded it? That's **exactly** what science is **supposed** to do.